# how can I actively get my cpu usage higher using matlab

Tags: matlab

In order to check my cpu, I need a way to get it's usage up. way up.
to somewhere between 70%-100%. it needs to use all of the cores,
and if there is a way so I can control the usage, it would be great.

So, I'm looking for a matlab code/ idea to make it happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my PC it works like this. f is a factor to pause. if I set it to 0 I get 100% load, if it's set to 0.25 I get 90% load. 0.5 50%

So it's not lineair, but it does give control

```
A=rand(1000);
f=0.25;
for ct = 1:1000
    tic
    hess(A);
    pause(toc*f)
end
```

You can break out of the loop with `ctrl-c` ofcourse.

You could also directly read out the CPU usage of the process and use that as a feedback for the time to pause, but that might be needlessly complicated for what you want to do.

```
CPUs=double(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);
P = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter('Process', '% Processor Time', 'MATLAB'); %perforamce counter
A=rand(1000);N=1000;
p_goal = 50; %desired CPU usage in percentage
f=1;
p=nan([1,N]);
for ct = 1:N
    tic
    hess(A);
    if f>0
    p(ct)=P.NextValue/CPUs; %percentage of CPU used by matlab
    if p(ct)<p_goal,f=f-0.01;end
    if p(ct)>p_goal,f=f+0.01;end
    pause(toc*f)
    plot(p);ylabel('cpu usage');title(sprintf('f=%.2f',f));drawnow;
    end
end
```

Comment: No, it works on all cores on my i5 matlab 2017a. Calculation of the hessian is already parallelized apperently.